# WCF client error only when running from Windows Server 2003: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.HttpBindingBase

Tags: .net, wcf

We run a WCF service on a website which we can access with the client exe file from everywhere except on 2 Windows 2003 servers (using Remote Desktop). It gives the following error:

> Service channel assignment failed: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.HttpBindingBase' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.*

The RD does run .Net 4 (the target framework) and I can't figure out what else I should do to get it also running on these systems. As written, the very same client using the same service runs fine from e.g. my own Windows 8 PC. What could be wrong?

Comment: How are WCF and RDP related here? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httpbindingbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class `HttpBindingBase` presents in .NET 4.5 **only**.

Comment: Indeed and I'm currently checking if this is the cause. The relation: I just run the WCF client .exe on PC's as well as from RD environments. The client seems indeed to work on 2 servers with .Net 4.5 (+ lots of PC's) and not on 2 within only .Net 4 - I'll ask the client to update to see if that solves it. But I am still unsure where this "HttpBindingBase" error comes from. I don't use this class explicitly anywhere in the client code, which is also targeted at .Net 4.0. I'll come back with this asap.

Comment: Later I found out that some mix-up exists between .Net 4 (targetted) programs which apparently can resolve using .Net 4.5 classes! With my program language the solution was to compile it in a .Net 4 environment (a Vista based VM was fine for that) and then it worked in the Server 2003 of my client.